# Unlocking apps on "recent apps" screen on AOYODKG Tablet 10-inch

Tags: recents-screen

I have AOYODKG Tablet 10-inch updated all the way. On the "recent apps" screen, there are locked apps, and I want to unlock them.

[image]

I've looked through many websites and tried through settings, and I've tried pushing the actual lock button to unlock the app. There is also no 3-dot on the top-right of the app.

How to unlock those apps? I would also love to disable the feature if possible.

Comment: Did you try long pressing the cards?